# jQuery.get() how can my output be auto recognized as JSON?

Tags: json, jquery

I'm using jQuery.get() to perform an AJAX call to a service.
My service returns a JSON object in this form

```
{
    "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
    "name" : "localhost"
}
```

That's it (no html tags)

if I use jQuery.get() without specifying that my output is "json" (so leaving the 4th parameter empty) the output of the service is not automatically recognized as JSON.

Did I make any mistake in formatting the service output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the output is correct.

The result is most likely not returned with the content type `application/json` but for example `text/html`, which would lead jQuery to think that it's not JSON.

If the content type doesn't match the data, you should specify the data type.

Related: [how does jquery guess the better datatype in Ajax method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787548/how-does-jquery-guess-the-better-datatype-in-ajax-method)