# Can't echo jquery (with ajax) variable in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, variables

I'm trying to post a variable through ajax. But it won't echo the variable in php.

This are the variables (these are working, seen in the log):

```
 $("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function(e, data){console.log("min: " + data.values.min + " max: " + data.values.max);});
```

The Ajax part:

```
$("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function (e, data) {

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "text",
   url: "../test.php",
   data: { minValue: data.values.min, maxValue: data.values.max },
   async: false,
   success: function(data){
      alert('yeah')

    },
     error: function(xhr) {
             alert('fail') // if your PHP script return an erroneous header, you'll land here
            }
 });
});

</script>
```

And php echo:

```
<?php

if ( $_POST ) {

        echo $_POST[ 'minValue' ];
            }
?>
```

Now why does it not echo the post? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because the ajax `success` callback merely alerts, but does nothing with the response data?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That makes sense indeed.. thought it was just a check to see if it works.

Comment: I've posted an answer, based on my comment with an additional recommendation on the `dataType` property

Answer (score 1):

The echo result is returned in the data variable passed to success method. It won't appear unless you do

```
alert(data)
```

Comment: okay that makes sense.. than what is the line to just use the variable in php? So no alerts.

Comment: why you want to use it in php? you may want to use it in jQuery you get the data and insert it in a specific html element.

Comment: I know, it's is just a check to see if it recieves the value. Eventually I will use the values so they can be saved and updated

Comment: Yes you can use the values and then whatever you want to return or view as a response to the ajax request you will echo back it and then in JS you will put it the appropriate html element.

Comment: You are doing alert(data) in the success method inside the js right?

Comment: Yes indeed, please see my new question, the problem is better explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488180/ajax-alert-error-fatal-error-class-not-found-while-page-works-fine

Answer (score 1):

When you do echo in your PHP script it will be sent back to the ajax call as a response. So you must check in the success part of the $.ajax. So do,

```
....
success: function(data) {
  alert(data);
},
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok seeing as my comment turned out to be the answer, here goes:
Change the `success` callback to do something with the data:

```
success: function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
}
```

I'd also recommend *not* setting the `dataType` explicitly. jQ does a good job at figuring out what the response's datatype is, and when sending an object litaral (like you're doing) it also does a smashing job at dealing with that, too.

[Check this question for more details on how jQ *"guesses"* the datatype of the resonse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787548/how-does-jquery-guess-the-better-datatype-in-ajax-method)
As you can read in [the API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the default datatype is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, so sending an object literal is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function(e, data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: "../test.php",
        data: { minValue: data.values.min, maxValue: data.values.max },
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
//          alert('yeah')
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            alert('fail') // if your PHP script return an erroneous header, you'll land here
        }
    });
});
```